# launch virtual machine on remote computer with X forwarding

Tags: x11, virtualbox, remote

Is it possible to launch a virtual machine (using `Virtual Box`) on a remote machine and just forward the screen using `X11` tunneling?

I tried this from my remote host:

```
$ssh user@myhost -X virtualbox
```

which launched the virtual box manager but it didn't let me start any of the virtual machines and gave me an error like:

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine GE Win7.

The virtual machine 'GE Win7' has terminated unexpectedly during startup with exit code 1 (0x1).

Result Code: NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: Machine
Interface: IMachine {480cf695-2d8d-4256-9c7c-cce4184fa048}
```

Any way I can get this going?

Answer (score 1):

- Configure the VM to allow remote display access (this only need to be done once, you might also use the GUI):

`VBoxManage modifyvm "GE Win7" --vrde on`

- Use the command line to start the VM in headless mode:

`ssh server VBoxManage startvm "GE Win7" --type headless`

- Launch the remote desktop viewer:

`rdesktop server:3389`

Beware that no firewall is blocking the rdp (TCP port 3389) traffic.